# Hand out different public address from one router

Tags: networking, router, ip-address

Recently, we got a WiFi router. We got that working. But there is a problem. Our university provides every individual with user login IDs and passwords. We can't access any website which is not on our university's server without authenticating with these credentials. And that router is working on a LAN connection provided to me by my university in my room with a static IP address. If We use multiple devices on this router, it asks for authentication from only one of them. Since, our data usage is tracked(No, it isn't. I'm just curious about how to do this), none of us were ready to login on the router(No one wants their data usage to be unusually high). So, is there any way I could set it up so that rather than allocating different local addresses to all the devices, it allocates different public addresses to all of them? I've a range of IP address which we get allocated whenever we connect to some router which belongs to my university.

Comment: Your university is only going to assigned the router a single ip address.  Getting the router assigned multiple LAN addresses won't be possible given the configuration of the university's network.

Comment: Well, technically it's possible, but needs some manual setup _by the network admins_.

Comment: The way you describe it suggests the system administrators have misconfigured their end.  If they expect multiple users to share an IP address, but only authenticate one, then it will always result in the authenticated person appearing to drive the traffic.  Have you spoken to them?

Comment: @Paul: Nah, sounds more like they _don't_ expect multiple users to share an IP address, but OP ended up doing that anyway, by buying and connecting a home router with NAT to the network. In which case it would be best to reconfigure the router device to "bridge mode" instead.

Comment: @Ramhound There are some routers which belong to the institute. Those router do actually handout different ip addresses. How do they work? I'm just curious, not saying that you're wrong.

Comment: @grawity I was aiming for benefit of the doubt for a change with this frequent scenario

Comment: Yes, the case @grawity describes. Any possibility that i could do this without contacting the network admins?

Comment: @AyushTulsyan The routers that the sysadmins are in control of work exactly the same way as any other router.  They are just configured by the sys admins to provide more than one IP address (as is the router that your router connects to).   There is no magic there, and as pointed out, the admins would need to provide this to you, you cannot do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks Paul and grawity. I'll read about bridging routers and see if network admins allow me to do what I'm trying to.

Comment: You _might_ be able to put the router in bridge mode and turn off DHCP but I doubt it... as is the theme of all these comments, it depends on choices the university admins have made.

Comment: The only way to assign different addresses on the university level to each client on the router is to turn off NAT or use IPv6. However, it may be that multiple clients on the university level are already sharing a public IP on the WAN level, so even this may not be possible.